# Alternative to IF statement with multiple conditions which are all equal to same value

Tags: vba

Is there a better way than this? (assuming all the vars will equal zero)

```
If var1 = 0 Or var2 = 0 Or var3 = 0 Or var4 = 0 Or var5 = 0 Or var6 = 0 Then
    'do something
End If
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a `Select Case`. It will also short circuit the evaluation (unlike the `If` statement):

```
Select Case 0
    Case var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6
        'do something
End Select
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't realised you could use select case like that!

Comment: @Slab - `Select Case` is pretty versatile - I use `Select Case True` and `Select Case False` a lot because of the short-circuiting behavior.

Comment: Oh OK, I'm cancelling the marching band.

Comment: @Vityata "assuming all the vars will equal zero".

Comment: If you need to test multiple *different* values, it would be [more like this](https://pastebin.com/WivPMmHq).

Comment: Ah so it wont work if I was checking if they were all equal to a non-zero number?

Comment: @Slab, It will work as long as you're testing if all the vars are the *same number*. If you need to test *different* conditions, then use either `Select Case True` or `Select Case False` as needed.

Comment: Ok, thats what I thought. Sorry I didn't write much in the OP, but that is exactly the question I was asking - a better way to test all the vars are equal to the same number. Thanks

Comment: @Slab - welcome. In your question you needed to write `And` not `Or`.

Comment: Sorry I actually did mean `or`, I want to know if at least one of them is equal to zero.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a short-circuiting function that bails out when it finds a value that matches the criteria:

```
Public Function MatchesAny(ByVal value, ParamArray values()) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        If values(i) = value Then
            MatchesAny = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

And now you can do this:

```
If MatchesAny(0, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6) Then
```

And if you need to bail out when any value *doesn't* match the criteria, then you can have a similar function with the inverse logic:

```
Public Function MatchesAll(ByVal value, ParamArray values()) As Boolean
    MatchesAll = True
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        If values(i) <> value Then
            MatchesAll = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Used like this:

```
If MatchesAll(0, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6) Then
```

Comment: Not needed, there was a change in the OP's needs (see the last comment)...

Comment: @Vityata meh, can't hurt to have these two anthagonistic functions anyway

Comment: Note: for production use I'd probably test if `values(LBound(values))` actually contains an array, so that you can make use it with an array reference *and* inline-enumerated values. Being `Variant` values, it should also work with dates, strings, and (barring floating-point rounding errors) single/double values. Remember to check for `IsError` too, if used with values from an Excel range.

Comment: This is a really nice solution, many thanks. I will remember this for the future.