# Need the MsgBox to appear only once when the condition is met on the form and the command button to disappear when the MsgBox appears

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that needs to be filled in. However, the code I have written for conditions don't seem to work in its entirety. The message box doesn't appear even though the condition is met, also the box doesn’t disappear when the condition is met.

I need the message box to appear once and the command button to be invisible when the condition that makes the message box appear is met.

Please help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)                       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Cells(12, 12) = "" Or Cells(14, 12) = "" Or Cells(16, 12) = "" Or Cells(18, 12) = "" Or Cells(20, 12) = "" Or Cells(22, 12) = "" Or Cells(24, 12) = "" Or Cells(26, 12) = "" Or Cells(28, 12) = "" Or Cells(30, 12) = "" Or Cells(47, 12) = "No" Then
        Range("L11").Select
        Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False

        If Cells(12, 12) = "Yes" Or Cells(14, 12) = "Yes" Or Cells(16, 12) = "Yes" Or Cells(18, 12) = "Yes" Or Cells(20, 12) = "Yes" Or Cells(22, 12) = "Yes" Or Cells(24, 12) = "Yes" Or Cells(26, 12) = "Yes" Or Cells(28, 12) = "Yes" Or Cells(30, 12) = "Yes" Then
            Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False
            'Prompt Msg Box
            MsgBox ("Please Fill In Box Below")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else  
        If Target.Range("$L$12") = "Yes" Or Target.Range("$L$14") = "Yes" Or Target.Range("$L$16") = "Yes" Or Target.Range("$L$18") = "Yes" Or Target.Range("$L$20") = "Yes" Or Target.Range("$L$22") = "Yes" Or Target.Range("$L$24") = "Yes" Or Target.Range("$L$26") = "Yes" Or Target.Range("$L$28") = "Yes" Or Target.Range("$L$30") = Yes And Range("B34").Characters.Count >= "5" Then
            Range("B34").Select
            Me.CommandButton1.Visible = True               
        ElseIf Cells(5, 4) > "" Or Cells(6, 4) > "" Or Cells(7, 4) > "" Or Cells(8, 4) > "" Or Cells(12, 12) = "No" Or Cells(14, 12) = "No" Or Cells(16, 12) = "No" Or Cells(18, 12) = "No" Or Cells(20, 12) = "No" Or Cells(22, 12) = "No" Or Cells(24, 12) = "No" Or Cells(28, 12) = "No" Or Cells(30, 12) = "No" Or Cells(47, 12) = "" Or Cells(47, 12) = "Yes" And Cells(49, 3) > "" Then
            Me.CommandButton1.Visible = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Else
            Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't appear you ever use the MsgBox function to create one.

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your sheet? Also, as a side note, you shouldn't use things like **`.Select`** or **`.Activate`** when using `VBA` as a general rule

Comment: The .Select was entered to see if the condition being met was working as a way to test. Did you want a snapshot of the actual excel form?

Comment: `Debug.Print` usually works pretty well for non-invasive diagnosis. Can you explain what you mean by "*the box* doesn't disappear when the condition is met"? Was that meant to be *the CommandButton*?

Comment: Yes I meant the command button

Comment: Put a stop (i.e. click the margin) on the `If` block that contains the MsgBox line then run your code. Then hit `F8`...if the code block isn't entered (and that must be the case if you're not seeing the message box), then you know there's something amiss with your conditional statement.

Comment: Also where would I input the Debug.Print function?

Comment: For testing, in lieu of selecting a cell to show that a certain block of code has been entered, you can simply enter the line `Stop` where you want to halt your program so you can more easily troubleshoot.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon how would I input this function?

Comment: Issue I have now is that the MsgBox does appear and the command box does dissapear, but when the condition of the characters within Range.B34 to be longer or equal to 5 it doesn’t reappear

Comment: Looks like that `And` should be an `Or` then? TBH these conditions are extremely hard to read/maintain. I would suggest you pull them into their own function or Boolean variables, to simplify the `If` condition and make it easier to spot a bug in the logic.

Comment: `Debug.Print` outputs to the immediate pane (Ctrl+G), which is your new best friend ;-)  ...you can use it just like any `MsgBox` call, `Debug.Print "Target: " & Target.Address`

Answer (score 0):

> when the condition of the characters within Range.B34 to be longer or equal to 5 it doesn’t reappear

This one then:

```
    If Target.Range("$L$12") = "Yes" Or _
       Target.Range("$L$14") = "Yes" Or  _
       Target.Range("$L$16") = "Yes" Or _
       Target.Range("$L$18") = "Yes" Or _
       Target.Range("$L$20") = "Yes" Or _
       Target.Range("$L$22") = "Yes" Or _
       Target.Range("$L$24") = "Yes" Or _
       Target.Range("$L$26") = "Yes" Or _
       Target.Range("$L$28") = "Yes" Or _
       Target.Range("$L$30") = Yes And _
       Range("B34").Characters.Count >= "5" _
 Then
```

Since this is a `Worksheet.Change` handler, the `Target` parameter is a reference to the cell that was just changed. `Target.Range("$L$12")` makes little sense then, as that would be relative to whatever cell was modified, and not the cell at `$L$12`.

`Range("B34")` looks right though: it's implicitly `Me.Range("B34")`, i.e. cell `$B$34` on that specific worksheet.

So I expect none of the `Target.Range(...) = "Yes"` conditions ever evaluate to `True`.

That makes the `And` operation never evaluate to `True` either.

---

Let's clean this up. Start with a [MatchesAny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298776/1188513) function:

```
Public Function MatchesAny(ByVal value, ParamArray values()) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        If values(i) = value Then
            MatchesAny = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

That will significantly improve the efficiency of evaluating all these conditions: now as soon as the result is known, we return the result. Chaining `Or` operators on the other hand, makes the `If` statement be fully evaluated before VBA can know whether or not to enter the conditional block.

The condition becomes:

```
If Me.Range("B34").Characters.Count >= 5 And _
    MatchesAny("Yes", Me.Range("L12").Text, _
                      Me.Range("L14").Text, _
                      Me.Range("L16").Text, _
                      Me.Range("L18").Text, _
                      Me.Range("L20").Text, _
                      Me.Range("L22").Text, _
                      Me.Range("L24").Text, _
                      Me.Range("L26").Text, _ 
                      Me.Range("L28").Text, _
                      Me.Range("L30").Text) _
Then
```

Note that this isn't equivalent: in your version, the number of characters in B34 is only relevant if L30 is "Yes"; in this version, the number of characters in B34 is relevant regardless of the other cells. This is because of how logical operator work: `And` has higher precedence than `Or`, so your condition is like `foo Or (bar And baz)` but mine is like `(foo Or bar) And baz`, which I believe is what you intended to do. Also the literal `5` shouldn't have been `"5"`, which is a string literal - it gets implicitly converted though, but such implicit conversions make things more confusing than they need to be.

The unqualified `Cells` calls at the top are confusing too: why refer to `L12` as `Range("$L$12")` in one place, but as `Cells(12, 12)` in another?

```
If Cells(12, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(14, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(16, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(18, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(20, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(22, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(24, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(26, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(28, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(30, 12) = "" Or _
   Cells(47, 12) = "No" _
Then
```

I'd make it use the same addressing style (either works, but consistency matters), and again use `MatchesAny` to short-circuit the condition evaluation:

```
If Me.Range("L47").Text = "No" Or _
    MatchesAny("", Me.Range("L12").Text, _
                   Me.Range("L14").Text, _
                   Me.Range("L16").Text, _
                   Me.Range("L18").Text, _
                   Me.Range("L20").Text, _
                   Me.Range("L22").Text, _
                   Me.Range("L24").Text, _
                   Me.Range("L26").Text, _ 
                   Me.Range("L28").Text, _
                   Me.Range("L30").Text) _
Then
```

And now that it's obvious that the two conditions repeat themselves, I'd figure out a way to simplify it even further - say we call that bunch of specific cells the `InputCells`, then something like this makes sense:

```
Private Function AnyInputCellMatches(ByVal matchValue As String) As Boolean
    AnyInputCellMatches = MatchesAny(matchValue, _
        Me.Range("L12").Text, _
        Me.Range("L14").Text, _
        Me.Range("L16").Text, _
        Me.Range("L18").Text, _
        Me.Range("L20").Text, _
        Me.Range("L22").Text, _
        Me.Range("L24").Text, _
        Me.Range("L26").Text, _ 
        Me.Range("L28").Text, _
        Me.Range("L30").Text)
End Function
```

And now we have something like this:

```
If AnyInputCellMatches("") Or Me.Range("L47").Text = "No" Then
    Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False
ElseIf AnyInputCellMatches("Yes") And Me.Range("B34").Characters.Count >= 5 Then
    Me.CommandButton1.Visible = True
End If
```

Which makes it much easier to tell whether there's a problem somewhere, and makes only one place to maintain the list of cells that need to be checked.

Comment: Thanks for this..ive tried incorporating your code but for some reason it does not work even with conditions laid out. A 'MsgBox' does not appear nor does the 'CommandButton' dissapear upon conditions being met

Comment: @SHoublon if the condition was met, the body is executed. The conditions are not met - or the conditions *as written* mean something other than what you think they do... the conditional blocks would absolutely run if their condition was met. You can place a breakpoint (F9), run the code, then inspect the values. If everything is as expected, you can edit your question to describe in plain words what the conditions are =)

Comment: Ok. Presume i'm a novice at implementing your code above. How would I complete the code in its entirety? For example how would i make this `Public Function MatchesAny(ByVal value, ParamArray values()) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        If values(i) = value Then
            MatchesAny = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function`  Work with this `If Me.Range("B34").Characters.Count >= 5 And _
    MatchesAny("Yes", Me.Range("L12").Text, _
                      Me.Range("L14").Text,` etc etc

Comment: Bearing in mind it needs to work as someone fills out the form on a `Worksheet.Change` basis

Comment: @SHoublon as I said above, I'm not sure what the logic is or should be, and whether it's correct or not in the code you've provided. That said, looks like you're asking about the last snippet in this answer... I'm confused.